# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with an upload certificate that is not yet valid because it has been recently reset

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-keystore

I recently update my app when I try to upload on Playstore I lose my key password so have to reset my key and again upload Playstore, It says 
 `You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with an upload certificate that is not yet valid because it has been recently reset. You will be able to upload APKs or Android App Bundles again from Jun 26, 2021, 6:29:19 PM UTC.`

I change my Time Zone still not works.
Even I tried other answers but no luck,

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: If Google checks for a time it does so on server side. Therefore changing the time(zone) on client side will not have any effect.

Comment: I fulfilled given date and time but still it's showing that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved that problem by waiting one more day, then again I upload the same `.aab` file. It accepts without any errors.

Comment: Why does it happens?

Comment: I don't why It happens